# I want to use a %s in raw_input in python version 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use a `%s` in `raw_input` in python version 2.7. I wrote this code:

```
name = raw_input("Hello, please insert your name: ")
acpass = raw_input("Hi %s please insert your account password") % name
```

It doesn't work. This error appears:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why?

Answer (score 5):

```
acpass = raw_input("Hi %s please insert your account password: " % name)
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the nooby question

Comment: @user3100730 We all had to start somewhere.

Comment: @user3100730 Everyone was a nooby once.